# Why "your hand" is spelled ידכה instead of ידך?

Tags: hebrew, midrash, grammar-dikduk, bo

In שמות יג:טז:

> "וְהָיָה לְאוֹת **עַל־יָדְכָה** וּלְטוֹטָפֹת בֵּין עֵינֶיךָ כִּי בְּחֹזֶק יָד הוֹצִיאָנוּ יְהוָה מִמִּצְרָיִם׃"

the word ידכה is used. Why is it not spelled ידך?

Comment: There are hundreds of anomalous plene spellings in the Torah, which are rarely at all explainable using [tag:garmmar-dikduk] so seeking such an answer here in particular, without any other motivation, isnt particularly compelling as a question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Rashi (Shemos 13:9):

> **על ידך:** יד שמאל, לפיכך ידכה מלא בפרשה שניה (פסוק טז) לדרוש בה, יד שהיא כהה
>
> **upon your hand:** On the left hand. Therefore, in the second section, (Verse 16) יָדְכָה is written with the full spelling, to explain thereby [that it means] the hand (יָד) that is weaker (כֵּהָה).

[ie. יָדְכָה is a contraction of two words: יָד-כֵּהָה]

Comment: Is this cause, or effect?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to ask. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Is it spelled differently *because* there was an inherent reality that Tefillin had to be on the left hand so the text had to allude to this, or is Tefillin placed on the left hand *because* the word was spelled differently?

Comment: I believe, that in the Oral Torah Hashem clarified the intent of his command; saying that Tefillin needs to be put on the weaker hand, and revealed the scriptural allusion to this halacha.

Comment: Is that my first option or my second option (or neither)?

Comment: Do you agree with my understanding of the Oral Torah?

Comment: I agree that there is an Oral Torah which can clarify the Written Torah. But that's not the issue here. the issue here is whether the Written Torah was forced to be written in a certain way *because* of the Oral Torah.

Comment: "Forced"? Hashem is not forced to do anything. He could have left this halacha as "halacha le'Moshe m'sinai", which has no scriptural allusion.